# How to write an Encoder for a collection in Spark 2.1?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-encoders

I have this:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder

val mydata: Dataset[Row] = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", true).option("inferSchema", true).load("mydata.csv")
// CSV header: Time,Area,City
// CSV values: "2016-01","A1","NY"
//             "2016-01","AB","HK" etc

// ...somewhere in my aggregate:
def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Array[(String, Row)]] = ....
```

For the inner tuple in the `Array` I can write:

```
val rowEncoder = RowEncoder(mydata.schema)
Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING, rowEncoder)
```

but how can I write the `Encoder` for the outer `Array`?

Comment: can you give a reproducible example? what's in `my.data` ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to either use `RowEncoder` for complete structure:

```
val enc = RowEncoder(StructType(Seq(
    StructField("data", ArrayType(
        StructType(Seq(StructField("k", StringType), 
        StructField("v", df.schema))))))))
```

and convert data to reflect this:

```
Row(Seq(Row(string, Row(...), Row(sting, Row(...))))
```

or use static encoder for all fields.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your answer. I am already able to convert the single `Row`. My problem is the `Array`.